# set readonly value in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How to set readonly value in flutter as like input in HTML
Code in HTML,

and My code in Flutter is

```
new TextField(
               decoration: new InputDecoration(
                    labelText: "Input Nama",
                    hintText: "Input Nama",
                    border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(20.0))),
              ),
```

NOTED DOES NOT USE CONTROLLER

Comment: Try **`TextField(enabled: false)`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set textField property enabled to false.

```
TextField(
  enabled: false,
  ...
)
```

[Read More about textField](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField-class.html)

Comment: then where I can add my default value?

Comment: For that you should use TextFormField(initialValue: "Your value here"), since TextField doesn't have initialValue property.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show some text in the textfield then you can create a TextEditingController and initialise it with the text you want like : `TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();     _controller = "your text here"`; and giving the controller to the textField or else adding the `readOnly:` to the text field will do the job.

```
TextField(
    readOnly: true,
    decoration: new InputDecoration(
      labelText: "Input Nama",
      hintText: "Input Nama",
      border: new OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
      ),
    ),
  );
```

Comment: I have an example what I mean, in HTML is <input type="text" id="country" name="country" value="Norway" readonly> then where I input it in textbox is Norway automaticly. do u get a point?

Comment: then use hint text to show text and you can set readonly: true . hint text will work as the background text and you won't have to use a controller

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, Flutter has given us two properties for readonly. [From the docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField-class.html):

**enabled → bool?** If false the text field is "disabled": it ignores taps and its decoration is rendered in grey.

**readOnly → bool**
Whether the text can be changed.

To me, it sounds like `readonly` is for displaying information and will never be editable as it is not to be thought of as an interactive form control, whereas `disabled` is for a form field that is in a disabled state for whatever reason, but could potentially be enabled under some circumstance.